# Less than or lesser than?

Tags: comparisons

In the sentence, 'Sita weighs 5 kg less than her sister,' can 'lesser than' be used? If not, why so?

Comment: No, because "less than" is already a comparison.  It would be correct to say that Sita's weight is the lesser of the two.

Comment: 60 kg *is lesser than* 70kg, but "she weighs *less than* her sister" You don't normally say or write "lesser" after a verb.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would suspect very strongly that the writer of "60 kg is lesser than 70kg" is not a native English speaker.

Comment: @phoog  Oh, you're right. It's absolutely wrong! Must be the heat. Little, less, the least. How awful... I feel so embarrassed.

Answer (score 6):

No, lesser than cannot be used in that sentence. Because as @phoog said, "less than" is already a comparison.

Take a look at [comparative and superlative adjectives in Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting).

According Cambridge in the link above and this nice [article](http://englishplus.com/news/news0701.htm), the proper grammars we can use in these scenarios are:

1. verb + less than + noun
2. noun + To be + lesser than + noun

As you can see, your first sentence "Sita weighs 5 kg less than her sister" follows the first rule. To use lesser than, you should alter your sentence in a way to fit in second rule. 
Which is" Sita's weight (noun) is lesser than her sister's (noun)

Comment: Without justification, rationalization, substantiation, citation, or *something*, this is a comment, not an answer. Answers on SE (unlike, say, Yahoo! answers) must be supported, not simply declared.

Comment: In fairness it was @phoog who said that, not me.

Comment: This is *much* better. Can you make one more improvement, please? Update your answer to point to an authority/reference/grammar book/etc which states or supports that these are the two proper grammatical constructions for this scenario?

Comment: Boom!  Plus one, baby!

Comment: Thanks Dab Bron :) I'm new here but you taught me practically.